# Strategies to solve congruence problems

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Which strategy is best to use when solving problems of the following sort?   $$x^{29} \equiv 3\pmod {184}$$

Comment: Solve the congruence for each prime power dividing $184$ ([Euler's totient theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem) might help), then use [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Comment: How exactly would that look?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Let $\rm\ a,b,p,n = 3,5,23,29\ $ in the more instructive generalization below.

**Lemma** $\ $ If $\rm\ p\ne 2\:$ is  prime, and $\rm\:2p = a^2b\!+\!1\:$ and $\rm\ \color{#c00}{p\!-\!1\mid 3n\!+\!1}\ $ then

$\rm\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad x^n\! \equiv a\ \, \Rightarrow\, \ x \equiv ab^2\,\ \ (mod\ 8p)$

**Proof** $\ $ $\rm\:2p = a^2b\!+\!1\:\Rightarrow\:(a,2p)=1\:\Rightarrow\:(x,2p)=1,\:$ by $\rm\:x^n\!\equiv a\:\ (mod\ 2p).\ $ Hence

$\rm mod\ 8, p\!:\ x^{p-1}\! \equiv 1\ $ by little Fermat, $ $ and $\rm\ x\:$ odd $\rm\:\Rightarrow\: mod\ 8\!:\ x^2\equiv 1,\:$ and $\rm\:2\mid p\!-\!1.$

$\rm mod\ 8p\!:\ a \equiv x^n\Rightarrow\: a^{-3}\!\equiv x^{\color{#c00}{-3n}}\!\equiv x^{\color{#c00}{1+j\,(p-1)}}\! \equiv x.\ $ Finally $\rm\ a^{-3}$ is computed as follows

$\rm 2p = a^2b\!+\!1\:\Rightarrow\:4\mid a^2b\!-\!1\:\Rightarrow\:8p\mid(a^2b)^2\!-\!1,\:$ so $\rm\:mod\ 8p\!:\ (a^2b)^2\!\equiv 1\:\Rightarrow\:a^{-3}\!\equiv ab^2.$

Comment: You sir know how to roll! That is a very neat solution.

Answer (score 1):

$x^{29}\equiv3\pmod {184}$

$\implies x^{29}\equiv3\pmod {23}$ as $184=23\cdot8$

Now, $\phi(23)=22\implies x^{22}\equiv1\pmod{23}\implies x^{29}\equiv x^7\cdot x^{22}\pmod{23}\equiv x^7$

$\implies x^7\equiv3\pmod{23}\implies x^{21}\equiv 3^3\pmod {23}\equiv 4$

So, $4\cdot x^{22}\equiv x^{21}\cdot1\pmod{23}\implies 4x\equiv1\pmod {23}\equiv 24$

So, $x\equiv6\pmod {23}$

Similarly, $ x^{29}\equiv3\pmod 8$ as $184=23\cdot8$

As $\lambda(8)=2, x^2\equiv1\pmod 8$
$\implies x^{29}=(x^2)^{14}\cdot x\equiv x\pmod 8\implies x\equiv3\pmod 8$

Now, apply [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), to find $x\equiv 75\pmod {184}$

Comment: $\lambda$ is the Carmichael Function (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html) and $\phi$ is the totient function (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersTotientTheorem.html)